# how to split a query with 'AND' and/or 'OR' arguments in it in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

how to split a query with 'AND' and/or 'OR' arguments in it in jquery?
Suppose iam having

```
A=( 1=1,FirstName='aaa' or FirstName='bbb' and FirstName='ccc' or FirstName='ddd' and FirstName='eee')
```

Now i want to split 'A' with 'and' & 'or' and get the result as below

```
A=(FirstName='aaa' , FirstName='dddd' , FirstName='bbb' , FirstName='dddd' , FirstName='cccc')
```

but the thing is i may or may not have 'or' in the query, still it should produce a o/p with all the values after split. Please help.
Different types of queries could be as below:

```
A=( 1=1,FirstName='aaa' or FirstName='bbb' and FirstName='ccc' or FirstName='eee' and FirstName='fff')  
A=( 1=1,FirstName='aaa' and FirstName='bbb' and FirstName='ccc' and FirstName='ddd' and FirstName='fff')
A=( 1=1,FirstName='aaa' or FirstName='bbb' or FirstName='ccc' or FirstName='ddd' or FirstName='fff')
```

Query is not static i just gave an example, it could be any string.

Comment: Just replace `or` and `and` with `,`.

Comment: `str.replace(/or|and/g, ',')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A little know fact is that you can pass a regular expression as a separator to the [String `.split()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).

```js
var A = "FirstName='aaa' or FirstName='bbb' and FirstName='ccc' or FirstName='ddd' and FirstName='eee'";
A.split(/and|or/g);

/* result:
["FirstName='aaa' ", " FirstName='bbb' ", " FirstName='ccc' ", " FirstName='ddd' ", " FirstName='eee'"]
*/
```